# C# upload file with additional data

Tags: c#, file-upload, webclient

I'm using the following code to upload a file:

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
            byte [] res=w.UploadFile("http://gate.com/in.php", @"c:\image.gif");
```

How can I add additional post data like `name=test&value=test2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the WebClient class. You may take a look at a [blog post](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html) I wrote on this topic. You could also upload multiple files with the presented solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always send it in the querystring, like: "http://gate.com/in.php?name=test&value=test2"